# jQuery check if CSS width is greater than 0 then add CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I must be doing something wrong here. I want jQuery to check if the width of a CSS element is greater than 0 then add CSS property:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".neo-P4EMilestonesMilestone").each(function() {
        $(this).css('width') !=0) {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The class element has a default width of 0:

```
<div class="neo-P4EMilestonesMilestone" style="width:0">
```

I want jQuery to look into any .neo-P4EMilestonesMilestone classes and if the width IS NOT set to "0" then add "display:block". Like this:

```
<div class="neo-P4EMilestonesMilestone" style="width:10%;display:block;">
```

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: I want jQuery to add "display:block;" if the width is not "0".

Comment: I think for starters there's a syntax problem. Just before the innermost line, you have a curly brace but no "if", "function", "for", or anything else that would allow a block-separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify it to the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wpd05jzx/)

```
$('.neo-P4EMilestonesMilestone').each(function () {
    $(this).css('display', $(this).width() > 0 ? 'block' : '');
});
```

Your code snippet wasn't working for a couple reasons. For one, there were syntax errors. In addition, when you retrieve the element's width via `$(this).css('width')`, the `px` unit is included. You would have had to parse the string `parseInt($(this).css('width'), 10)` in order to check if it is greater than `0`. Instead of doing that, you can just retrieve the width using `$(this).width()`, and then that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yuu have a few syntax errors. No `if` keyword and no closing braces.
See below.

```
$(".neo-P4EMilestonesMilestone").each(function () {
    if ($(this).width() != 0) {
        $(this).css({
            'display': 'block',
                'width': '10 % '
        });
    }
});
```